# How to make an active view type with classlist add and remove?

Tags: javascript, children

Ok so I have game list, which is currently styled in a thumbnail kind of view. I have made 3 other classes which when added change the child elements of the list elements to make a list view. I have one which changes the li's themselves, 2 which change the child nodes of that li.

I have two buttons which should control the users preferred view type. They have an active class which stays on to show it is the active view.

So here's the question, how do i select the li's, and there child elements, to replace the view. So when clicked, the list button will add those classes. I will also need the thumbnail view button to remove those classes but i can figure that afterwards.

The markup:

```
<div id="View">
    <button id="boxes" class="btn active" title="Thumnbnail View"         onclick="thumbview()">
      <i class="fas fa-th"></i>
    </button>
    <button id="lines" class="btn" title="List View" onclick="listview()">
      <i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i>
    </button>
  </div>

<div id="sortcontainer">
  <li class="game" id="75">
    <a href="Radiant_Defence.html"> 
      <img src="Games_images/radiantdefence/banner_image.png">
      <h2 class="title">Radiant Defence</h2>
      <h2 class="date" id="2012">(2012)</h2>
      <h3>75/100</h3>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="game" id="80">
    <a href="plantsvszombies2.html">
      <img src="Games_images/Plantsvszombies2/bannerimage.jpg">
      <h2 class="title">Plants vs Zombies 2</h2>
      <h2 class="date" id="2013">(2013)</h2>
      <h3>80/100</h3>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="game" id="45">
    <a href="link">
      <img src="games_category_placeholder.jpg">
      <h2 class="title">Some game</h2>
      <h2 class="date" id="2017">(2017)</h2>
      <h3>45/100</h3>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="game" id="80">
    <a href="link">
      <img src="games_category_placeholder.jpg">
      <h2 class="title">Fieldrunners 2</h2>
      <h2 class="date" id="2016">(2016)</h2>
      <h3>80/100</h3>
    </a>
  </li>



</div>
```

And the JavaScript I have so far (still new)

```
function listview() {
    var container = document.getElementById("sortcontainer");
    var li = container.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++);
    li.classList.add("lilistview");
};
```

Thankyou in advance if anyone has any suggestions

Comment: which child nodes does it change? the a tag?

Comment: I advise you to use JQuery, it's powerful and very intuitive when you have to manipulate DOM Tree

Comment: So the new classes to add are, to the li itself, the <img> and all the <h> tags. The <h> will all have the same class added though.

Comment: @BenjaminAudet i have used little bits of jquery but i really want to learn a lot of the basics of javascript first so i understand whats happening within the jquery code.

Comment: Yes but what you try to do is not a good practise (add a class to all element you want to modify) if the parent itself got it, you have to use inheritance to do it

Comment: How would i go about doing it? Each child has a seperate class which needs to change. It cant be done just by changing the parent

Comment: With JQuery you can do a thing like that : `$('li').children()` that returns an array containing the children of all li